# change iframe to script includes the iframe

Tags: javascript, php

I have this part of code:

```
<div class="embed">&lt;iframe id="iframe" src="<?php echo DOMAIN_NAME; ?>demo?q=<?php echo $number;?>"&gt;<body></body>&lt;/iframe&gt;</div>
```

and i want to make an asychronous script that includes this iframe. So in the end i will give in my clients the asynchronous script code instead of iframe. I want to do that for 1 main reason. In case my website is down i don't want to decrease the speed of the websites/portals that my clients have post my iframe.

when somebody clicks on embed div then an iframe given to my clients. i want to give an asychronous script instead of this iframe.
Is it possible? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like

```
var cosnikFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
cosnikFrame.width=450;
cosnikFrame.height=300;
cosnikFrame.setAttribute("scrolling","no");
cosnikFrame.style.border=0;
document.body.appendChild(cosnikFrame);
cosnikFrame.src="http://example.com/demo.php?q=12aA1b35A4a";
```

or to defer to after load using for example jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("body").append('<iframe width='450' height='300' scrolling="no" style="border:0" src="http://example.com/demo.php?q=12aA1b35A4a"></iframe>');
});
```

Comment: thats the script i have to give in my clients or this is going to create my script?

Comment: the iframe generating automatically in my php file. i want to create a dynamically script instead of iframe..

Comment: Please update your question with the exact result of what you want

Comment: Did not help. What exactly do you mean? What will the html look like on the client's site?